# Sizing images to mimic it's natural height/width without specifying any height in the parent Container

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have a PhysicalModel which contains text + an image. My goal is to Size the Container (the one with height: 300) to the actual height of the image. Images are taken from database which can be different heights/widths. In other words, the goal is to replicate a similar result to Twitter/X but whenever I remove the height of the container it show an error: RenderBox not laid out.

Any help towards the right direction would be highly appreciated!

```
return PhysicalModel(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 2,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          'username',
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            fontSize: 15.5,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            letterSpacing: 0.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 2),
                        Text(
                          'date',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                         const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                right: 14, left: 14, top: 4, bottom: 8),
                            child: Text(
                              'text',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 300,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                          color: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                        height: 25,
                                        width: 25,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    imageUrl: _post.aPostUrl,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Use a combination of ConstrainedBox (to give maximum height/width) and FittedBox (to specify how to handle mismatches) to make your image what it wants to be naturally.